# How do I hide the previous Stack header when I navigate to the new Stack screen in expo router?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm using expo router, and want to know how I can remove the previous stack header from the screen, the replace method is not working as expected.

My file structure looks like this:

```
-app
 -exercise
   -layout.tsx
   -index.tsx
   -Active.tsx
 -layout.tsx
```

app/layout.tsx

app/exercise/layout.tsx

```
<Stack>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="index"
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
      presentation: "modal",
    }}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Active"
    options={{
      headerShown: true,
    }}
  />
</Stack>
```

currently:

When I'm home, and I press on an exercise, I navigate to the index.tsx of the exercise folder

```
router.navigate(`/exercise`);
```

When I'm on that index, and I press start, I'm sent to  the /exercise/Active.tsx

```
router.replace({
          pathname: "exercise/Active",
        });
```

when I'm on the exercise/Active, I get two stack screens on top, the exercise and the active
[image]

What I want:
when I'm on the active screen, I don't want the exercise header to be shown, I know how to remove the Active header by simply adding "headerShow:false" in the exercise/layout Stack, but how do I remove the exercise header, which exists on the app/layout.

I can't set the headerShown to false on the app/layout on exercise layout, because that'll remove the header when I'm on the app/index screen, I only want to remove it when I'm on the active screen, and when I go back from the /exercise/active screen to /exercise/index screen I want the /exercise header to be shown.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using router.replace? Can you not do router.navigate(`/exercise/active`); ?

Comment: Hi thank you, that was just part of testing, not really the problem I was having. I figured it out now, you can check the answer.

Comment: I should say that I prefer react navigation for all my apps. I've tried Expo routers and I felt like I was trapped in. React navigation is a little bit more code but it gives you so much more space. Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the case for other people as well. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, and I thought I would answer it because I feel like it's a common problem for someone just starting out on app/dev.

The trick here is to set `headerShown` for the exercise route on the `app/layout` to `false` and on the `app/exercise/layout` set the `headerShown` for the index to true and add a headerTitle "exercise".

This will give the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your app/layout you probably have a stack. If so do this. This hides the extra header from all the screens on your exercise stack (app/exercise/layout)

```
<Stack> 

  <Stack.Screen name="exercise" options={{headerShown: false}} /> 

  <Stack.Screen name="index" /> 

</Stack>
```

If you don't have a Stack in your app/layout then use a  instead and it will solve the issue.

So something like this

```
const Layout = () => {
   return <Slot />
}
```